# Big schema change: does it make sense to do it on the dev server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**Basically**: if I upload a bunch of data generated from my dev server with the bulk uploader, will key references stay consistent?

**Elaboratedly**:

I have a big schema change I want to do.  Every night I have a six-hour period with almost zero activity, during which I could set the app to read-only mode.

I don't really want to deal with figuring out how to do error correction, mapreduce, etc.  Since I can take the app down for a while, does it make sense to download the data with the bulk uploader, process it on my dev server, and upload the new data?

I'll be happy enough to figure out MapReduce eventually to clean up the dead data lying around.  All of my entity kind names are changing, so having a bunch of old, outdated data around for a while won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this if you want, of course. Without knowing the nature of the changes, it's hard to say if this will be any easier than writing a mapreduce to do it.

An easier option would probably be to use remote_api to modify the data, without explicitly dumping and restoring it. The same transfer to and from your local machine happens, but without the extra steps needed.

Comment: Well, what I really don't want to do is make sure that every step of the transition will be fail-safe.  I figure that if I do it all on a local dev machine, there won't be any time-out or connection errors.  It seems like if I use remote_api to modify the data, the app will have to be in allow-writes mode, and I'll have to make sure that I pick up on any new data entry... etc.  As a complete newbie to appengine, it just seems much simpler to process the data on my machine. Would you recommend any articles or books about the topic of a transition like this on live data?

Comment: @Riley You could simply modify your UI to not accept any input from users while updating the data. If you don't do that, you'll have the same issue while uploading your modified data. It's difficult to recommend anything based on a "transition like this", because you haven't actually specified the details of what the transition is. In general, I would recommend doing it online, using a mapreduce, where possible.